# What is link Utilization factor?

Tags: communication

I am trying to learn link utilization factor in data communication but can't find the actual definition of it.Can anyone give me an accurate definition of link utilization factor with the formula??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply the amount that the link is being used. It you have an ideal link datarate of 1 Gbps (Giga bits per second) but can only get 800 Mbps then your channel utilization is 0.8 or 80%.

Utilization expressed as a formulae will change according to where you are in the protocol stack. At the physical layer it will depend upon your modulation scheme, if you use 8b/10b then it will be close to 80%, the trend is towards higher ratio's like 128b/130b with utilization of 98.5% +.

In a higher layer you will be dealing with packet overhead, error correction codes, preambles and signalling bits.  In this case the utilization will be the \$ \dfrac{data payload}{data payload + overhead} \$.  You don't say what your scheme but all standard schemes have published data.